# Is it OK if I ask Multiple choice questions or fill in blanks on SE sites

Tags: discussion

Is it OK if I ask multiple choice or fill in the blanks questions on SE sites? I feel rather bad doing this since such type of questions show no effort..but is it allowed?

Comment: Why the downvote? just say yes or no!!

Comment: It'll probably depend on the site, but it would likely be not allowed on most of the sites. What sort of question are you trying to ask?

Comment: mostly physics like a beam of electron follows a so and so path if..

Comment: @Tom Probably because we *can't* "just say yes or no" - this question is extremely open-ended. Are you just copy-pasting a homework problem and it's four multiple-choice options? Because if so, that would not be on-topic anywhere. It is possible to put research effort into a multiple-choice question and *make it on-topic*, though.

Comment: @animuson great..that should be the answer

Comment: OK. I'm not a Physics kind of person, but you'd want to check with that specific community if they allow homework-like questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about it this way: if you leave off the fact that it's multiple choice, is it still a good question? If so, it's fine. If not, it's not going to be improved by multiple choice selections.

To satisfy the general request for effort, you can indicate what you've tried to answer the question. If you don't know where to begin, you'll need to check that site's meta to see if such questions are acceptable.

In short: some sites will, and some sites won't. In general, I don't think it would be a problem anywhere so long as you show what you've done to solve the problem - but if you really don't know, you may want to ask on that site's specific meta.